# how to get class in javascript with colon syntax for making dynamic class like tailwind css

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, tailwind-css

i want to make dynamic class for hover , focus ,check and others. but I can't able to get those class format(hover:bg-sky-700) for using colon(:).it shows error in console. please provide an idea to make dynamic class like tailwinds. thank you.

```
<div class="single-bg bg_amber_5 hover:bg_green"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHKnK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class name contains reserved characters(`.`, `:`, `#` etc.) you need to escape it to avoid ambiguity using [`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape):

```js
// be careful you don't want to escape the leading "." since it meant to be indicating a class selector
const element = document.querySelector(`.${CSS.escape('hover:bg_green')}`);
console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="single-bg bg_amber_5 hover:bg_green"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hao Wu.it works properly.